# How to return a values from a method which prints its out put

Tags: bash, shell-script, yaml

I have a method which prints its content with 'printf'. I want the printed contents to be return.

```
parse_yml() {
   #some logics here
         printf("%s%s is %s", $1, code, $2, $3);
      }
```

In above code, "`printf("%s%s is %s", $1, code, $2, $3);`" prints the desired values. But I need to return all printed values concatenated so that the a variable which is outside the method can have final all values into a single variable. Something like below:

```
allContent=parse_yml.
```

I tried with defining a global variable called `r`, and instead of `printf` line:

```
r=$r$vn$2$3
```

and outside, when echoed, it was empty.

Any suggestion please how to return all values from that method ?

Comment: Have you tried with allContent=$(parse_yml file prefix) ?

Comment: @Débora: Please tag your posting correctly. You ask about a problem in the loop, and tag the posting as *bash*, but there is no bash-loop in your code. The only loops which occur are in your awk program.

Comment: With the edit that removed most of the code, all that's left in the function is a syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, whether I understood you right, but in bash, you grab output like this:

```
allContent=$(parse_yml.)
```

An

```
echo $allContent
```

should then reveal the same, like

```
parse_yml. > parse_yml.out
cat parse_yml.out
```

The filename parse_yml. looks a bit suspicious - no file ending? And usually, you have to either specify the absolute path, or the relative path, which would be

```
./parse_yml
```

except, if the current directory is in the PATH.

Comment: That is what actually I wanted.. this solved the problem. thanks